# Error creating ADO.Net Entity Data Model

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Some time back I created a small application that uses SQL CE 4.0 database with Entity Frameworks.

Unable to generate the model from the 4.0 database, I generated it from an identical 3.5 database schema, and then repointed the config files and updated the Provider references.

Today I needed to update the schema.

I updated the 3.5 database schema, updated the model, and then pointed the configs back to the 4.0 database.

Now I get the error though on build: "Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid"

After some hours of trying to sort this out, I have created a brand new solution, pointed it at the 3.5 database, and attempted to create a new ADO.Net Entity Data Model. The model is generated, but on building the solution I get the same error as before.

On my machine, both SQL CE 3.5 and SQL CE 4.0 are installed.

I have no idea what to try next short of removing both frameworks from the machine and reinstalling them all.

Comment: I cannot post as answer as I'm not 100% - but there seems to be some issue with different CE 4.0 versions on the machine. In my case reinstalling CE 4.0 helped. There are also couple other solutions to this, checking your machine config etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uninstalled all version of SQL Compact, rebooted and reinstalled SQL CE 3.5

All works fine now.

Comment: The Toolbox installtion does not interfer with the SQL Server Compact engine installtion in any way, so that assumption is wrong!

Comment: I accept it may not have been the toolbox, although downloading and running the SqlCe40Toolbox.exe application is the only thing I did between the last successful VS build of the project and the unsuccessful build.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my SQL Server Compact toolbox VS add-in to create the updated edmx file in your project, and via the about dialog you can also check if the 4.0 DbProvider is properly installed.

To do it, right click with the mouse over the database name ([your_database].sdf) and click on "Add Entity Data Model to current Project"

Comment: I hadn't seen the option in there to create the EDMX file - that could have saved me a lot of grief!